# Can't complete Cron Job when python code is embed (through reticulate) inside the R script

Tags: python, r, cron, schedule, reticulate

I've created an R script that first launches a python script through the `py_run_file()` function and then executes some R code. I need to schedule the launch of such script at a certain hour of the day, and hence I used the package `cronR`. Unfortunately, when I call the script function **just as a cron job**, the job freezes and doesn't end. Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(reticulate)

today <- Sys.Date()

use_python("~/miniconda3/bin/python3.8",
           required = TRUE)

py_run_file("~/Desktop/test.py")

print(paste("End on the",
            today))
```

This is the content of the `test.py` file:

```py
print("python script!")
```

Do you have any suggestion? Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some odd reason, whenever you run an R Cron Job using reticulate package, I figured after a lot of trial and error, we have to use it like this :

```
reticulate::use_python(python = '/usr/bin/python3', required = T)

reticulate::source_python("FULL_PATH_TO_PYTHON_FILE.py")
```

instead of importing the library using library(reticulate) this thing strangely works!